# How to Avoid conflict between jquery UI and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I am creating jquery collapsible set with sidebar and a search button. I need to apply bootstrap for this. If i include the bootsrap css file the collapsible is not visible.
Please help me to solve this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <meta name="author" content="www.frebsite.nl" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=yes" />

        <title>jQuery.mmenu demo</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo_collapsible.css" type="text/css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mmenu.css" />
                <link href="css/jqueryscripttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
                <!--<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />-->
      </head>
      <body>
       </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you [jquery-ui-bootstrap](http://jquery-ui-bootstrap.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/)
Also look at [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your bootstrap to omit some features in order to prevent confliction: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/